# pyautogui automating shift-down/up and ctrl-c doesn't work

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to get text from the screen automatically using pyautogui, with this code:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.press('esc')
pyautogui.press(['down','down','down','down'])
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
```

but the command `keyDown('shift')` doesn't work. Could someone help me with this error?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Is this ( https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/15 ) helpful?

Comment: I fix this error!
For some reason the shift does not work with the casplock or numlock activated, I made a command to find out if any of the two is active, if yes disable!

Comment: @user3815068, how did you get status of capslock and/or numlock? This doesn't seem to be available from pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

Pyautogui should let you use the hotkeys here, and you could probably tidy things up with a loop:

```
for i in range(0, times_to_run):
    pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'down')
```

Then you don't have to worry about using `keyUp` or `time.sleep()`.

Comment: for i in range(4):
    pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'down')

Comment: @AlwynMiranda are you sure you're not mixing up down with page-down? When I retried my code to see what might be wrong, I confused the two myself. But if you, say, highlight the "should" in my response and run the code, you will see a bit more text highlighted with each iteration, as should happen with shift-down. I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 7.